# Change the text of a JLabel - Beginner

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

My code;

```
package com.test;

import java.awt.EventQueue;

public class TestGU {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JLabel la;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public  void mainM() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    TestGU window = new TestGU();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void redefine(String text){
         la.setText(text);
    frame.repaint(); 

    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public TestGU() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        la = new JLabel("New label");
        frame.getContentPane().add(null);
    }

}
```

I am trying to change the Text of the Label from the main method (which is a separate class) shown below;

```
public class Test {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        TestGU g = new TestGU();
        g.mainM();
        g.redefine("New Value");
}
}
```

1.) When the main method is executed, i expected the label to have the text "New Value", but it still contains the text `New label`. Nothing has changed, how can i correct this?

Comment: `frame.getContentPane().add(null);` does not compile. Is that your real code? Also your code runs `initialize` twice so there are 2 TestGU objects.

Comment: The JLabel is never added to the frame either.

Comment: null means absolute layout right ?

Comment: *"null means absolute layout right ?"*  Wrong.  It means add nothing to it the content pane.  BTW - ***Use layouts!***

Comment: How could i add an absolute layout ?

Comment: An 'absolute layout' is not J2SE, AFAIU - it is a `null` layout by another name.

Comment: +1 for adding the code needed to figure out exactly what was going wrong ..and also for not extending `JFrame`.  ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you are creating two instances of `TestGU` and your `redefine` method changes the value of a label on an instance that isn't displayed.

Just checking my theory now....

Edit:
You don't need to create the 2nd instance; your mainM method should be;

```
public void mainM() {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

PS - I assume that your initialise method actually has this line right?

```
frame.getContentPane().add(la);
```

rather than `add(null)` as that doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look over this example for ideas.

[image: TestGU]

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.*;

public class AnotherClass {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
               TestGU g = new TestGU();
               g.redefine("New Value");
            }
        };
        EventQueue.invokeLater(r);
    }
}

class TestGU {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JLabel la;

    public void redefine(String text){
         la.setText(text);
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public TestGU() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        la = new JLabel("New label");
        frame.getContentPane().add(la);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
   }
}
```

Comment: Yes, but i want to change the text of the Label, from another class.

Comment: @AndrewThompson - don' be too hard on them, at least they didn't subclass `JFrame`.

Comment: @Qwerky Actually it's a 'HER'

Answer (score 2):

Never use JFrame as top level container.

Components added to JFrame are not registeder for listening by AWTEvent queue.

So your setText() does not create proper event to component to be repainted.

```
setContentPane( new JPanel(){{ add(la); }} );
```

And it will work as expected, without calling any paint/repaint methods.

Answer (score 1):

You created 2 instances of `TestGU` (1 in `Test` and 1 in `mainM()` in `TestGU`) and only 1 was visible. Change your `mainM()` method to this:

```
/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public void mainM() {
    this.frame.setVisible(true);
}
```