# Adding text to a label from another class - Simple Logic Issue

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jlabel

I have a label and a button in a class called `FrameTest`, when i press the button, a method named `buttonpressed` get's executed from the class `Test`. In this `buttonpressed` method i will set a text to the label found in the `FrameTest` class.

The problem i have is that, the text for the label is not getting set. The reason is that i am creating a separate object to call the `buttonpressed` method;

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    Test t = new Test();
                    t.buttonpress();
                }
```

and i am creating a separate object in the main method of the `Test` class to create the UI.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

         FrameTest f = new FrameTest();
         f.mainScreen();

    }
```

The full code as follows;

```
public class FrameTest extends JFrame {

private JPanel contentPane;
private JLabel lblLabel;
private FrameTest ft = this;

//private FrameTest frame;
/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public  void mainScreen() {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                //FrameTest frame = new FrameTest();
                //setVisible(true);

                FrameTest frame = ft;
                frame.setVisible(true);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}


public void writeLabel(String k){
    this.lblLabel.setText(k);

}

public FrameTest() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH); 

    //setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
    setContentPane(contentPane);

    lblLabel = new JLabel("LABEL");
    contentPane.add(lblLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Press");
    btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Test t = new Test();
            t.buttonpress();
        }
    });
    contentPane.add(btnNewButton, BorderLayout.WEST);
    //pack();
    setLocationByPlatform(true);
}

}
```

Test Class

```
public class Test {


public static void main(String[] args) {

     FrameTest f = new FrameTest();
     f.mainScreen();

}

public void buttonpress(){
     FrameTest f = new FrameTest();

     f.writeLabel("Button was pressed");

}
```

Comment: What might be the reason of doing so ? (I'm a beginner) and COuld you show me an example?

Comment: @sharonHwk btw, why are asking same questions again and again ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13415584/change-the-text-of-a-jlabel-beginner

Comment: possible duplicate of [Display text to a label from another class - JFrame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13470481/display-text-to-a-label-from-another-class-jframe)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Dont extend `JFrame` class unnecessarily.

2) dont use `setContentPane()` unless thats what you want. Rather just simply `JFrame#add(..)`.

3) Steer away from `EventQueue` and use `SwingUtilities` block rather

4) Dont forget to call `JFrame#pack();` before setting `JFrame` visible.

5) Java naming convention is CamelCase so `buttonPress()` is correct not `buttonpress()`

Here is an example I made (basically your code fixed):

**Test.java:** (This is the main class which will create an instance of your `FrameTest` and has the method to change `JLabel` text)

```
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Test {

    private static FrameTest f;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                f = new FrameTest();
                f.mainScreen();
            }
        });
    }

    void buttonPress() {
        f.writeLabel("Hello");
    }
}
```

**FrameTest.java:** (This class will show the `JFrame` and create a new instance of class `Test` to call `buttonPress()`):

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class FrameTest {

    private JPanel panel;
    private JLabel lblLabel;
    private JFrame frame;

    private void initComponents() {
        frame = new JFrame("Test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);

        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

        lblLabel = new JLabel("LABEL");
        panel.add(lblLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Press");
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Test t = new Test();
                t.buttonPress();
            }
        });

        panel.add(btnNewButton, BorderLayout.WEST);

        frame.add(panel);

        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void writeLabel(String k) {
        this.lblLabel.setText(k);
    }

    void mainScreen() {
        initComponents();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the class `TestJFrame ` a typo? did you mean `Test` ?

Comment: @sharonHwk finally understood what you wanted. Test must be the main class, which also holds the method to change JLabel. see update

Comment: Thank you. Let me try this out. but i kind of liked the previous solution.

Answer (score 1):

Pass your FrameTest object to the buttonpress method and use it there, instead of creating a new object:

```
public void buttonpress(FrameTest f) {
     f.writeLabel("Button was pressed");    
}
```

Change the invocation of the method like so:

```
btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Test t = new Test();
        t.buttonpress(FrameTest.this);
    }
});
```

You have to use `FrameTest.this` here, as you're inside of an anonymous class implementing ActionListener, so the normal `this` would reference to that anonymous class.

Comment: How do i add the parameter `FrameTest ` to  the `t.buttonpress();` method ?

Comment: The whole code is all but perfect, but from the Java point of view this will work. `Test t = new Test();` does not create the UI (this happens in the `main()` method, which is never called here.

Answer (score 1):

**-** Well the first approach is using `Composition` Principle, where you create an **instance** of `FrameTest.java` in `Test.java class` and then access the `Label` (use Getter Setters for this label in FrameTest) in `FrameTest.java` class using this instance.

**-** Second approach is a dirty and quick fix one, make the `Label` `static` in `FrameTest.java` class and directly set the value from `Test.java` class. Voila its done.....

**-** The reason your code is not working, cause you have created a very new instance of the `FrameTest class`. So now you either pass the `FrameTest` **Object Reference Variable** to `buttonpress()` method or make the `label` **static**.

**Eg:**

```
public class FrameTest extends JFrame {

private JPanel contentPane;
public static JLabel lblLabel;

.....

.....

}
```

**Or**

```
public void buttonpress(FrameTest f) {
     f.writeLabel("Button was pressed");    
}
```

**/////////////////////////// Edited Part ///////////////////////////////////**

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

class FrameTest extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JLabel lblLabel;
    private FrameTest ft = this;

    public void mainScreen() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {

                    FrameTest frame = ft;
                    frame.setVisible(true);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void writeLabel(String k) {
        this.lblLabel.setText(k);

    }

    public FrameTest() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);

        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        setContentPane(contentPane);

        lblLabel = new JLabel("LABEL");
        contentPane.add(lblLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Press");
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Test t = new Test();

                t.buttonpress(FrameTest.this); // Passing the current object to
                                                // the Test class
                                                // You can use just "this" , but
                                                // as we are in an Anonymous
                                                // Inner Class here,
                                                // we have to use
                                                // "Class_name.this"

            }
        });
        contentPane.add(btnNewButton, BorderLayout.WEST);
        // pack();
        setLocationByPlatform(true);
    }

}

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        FrameTest f = new FrameTest();
        f.mainScreen();

    }

    public void buttonpress(FrameTest f) { // Receiving the reference to the
                                            // current frame, but remember
                                            // THOUGH IT SEEMS that we are passing the
                                            // reference but still in
                                            //  Here and in Java its always pass
                                            // by copy.( ie pass by value).

        f.writeLabel("Button was pressed");

    }
}
```

Comment: I tried the first method. but since i am having my `main()` method (which is static) i will not be able to call the `f.mainScreen();` method.

Comment: @sharonHwk It was a general suggestion, pls see the example codes i gave

Comment: I would love to adopt your 1st solution, but can you tell me how can i call the `f.mainScreen();` method from the `main()` method of the `Test` class

Comment: @sharonHwk i have included the whole working code according to the 1st solution as asked by you... pls see the edited part.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your `Test` class like below

```
package com.test;

public class Test {

    private static FrameTest f;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        f = new FrameTest();
        f.mainScreen();

    }

    public void buttonpress() {
        f.writeLabel("Button was pressed");
    }
}
```

The actual problem was

1. You created a `FrameTest` variable `f` in main and shown the UI to user.
2. Then on button press you again created another `FrameTest` instance `f`, which does not map the original/first `f`

Now i treat the variable as a class variable and it works as expected

Comment: @DavidKroukamp the `Test` class is not the UI creation class. `Test` is the label updater class. UI creation is done at class `FrameTest`. You can try my code and make sure that it works.